# Codeigniter's redirect is not passing variable data

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a form to update some profile information. After making changes when the user clicks on the submit button my to be redirected to the profile page.

so after inserting the updated information into database I have the following code to redirect to the profile page:

database query goes here...

```
 redirect('studentprofile/get/$id');
```

Here the $id is the the profile id and "get" is the function and "studentprofile" is the controller. But this is not working at all. It seems like the "redirect" is not getting the value of $id.

When the user submits data it shows an error saying "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." and the URL looks like this

http://localhost/sundial/studentprofile/get/$id

would you please kindly tell me what is wrong with my script? Just for your information I am using Codeigniter

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the redirect path string to be in double quotes:

```
redirect("studentprofile/get/$id");
```

or write it like this:

```
redirect('studentprofile/get/'.$id);
```

Comment: Thank you SeanNieuwoudt. I tried the same thing but it didn't work but when I copied your script and pasted it just worked like a magic. Thanks again bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes use single quotes instead and btw that is not an issue of CodeIgnitor. Read more about strings: http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double